# Javascript Works on Desktop but only Partially Works on Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

The following is the full JavaScript code for a quiz. It works perfectly on desktop browsers. However, when I went to test it on my phone, it doesn't work.

Mobile loads the JSON quiz, but after all the answers are selected, it does not freeze all the selected answers and display the results. Instead, nothing happens, no result is shown/calculated, and the user can continue to select answers.

I'm not experienced with JavaScript on Mobile and don't know what is causing the problem.

I've deleted a few parts of the code that simply appended html in order to cut down on size.

You can view it here:  plnkr.co/edit/tkCQVxoIq9oOiApeUY66?p=preview

```
// Adds the functionality to check if an element has a class
HTMLElement.prototype.hasClass = function (className) {
    "use strict";
    if (this.classList) {
        return this.classList.contains(className);
    }
    return (-1 < this.className.indexOf(className));
};

// Adds the ability to remove classes from elements
HTMLElement.prototype.removeClass = function (className) {
    "use strict";
    if (this.classList) {
        this.classList.remove(className);
    }
    return this;
};

var BF_QUIZ = {};

BF_QUIZ.quiz = function () {
    "use strict";

    // Sets variables
    var highest_score, quiz_div, quiz_title, quiz_image, questions = [],
        results = [], inputs = [], answers = [], userAnswers = [],

    // Gets the Quiz "canvas"
    getQuizCanvas = function getQuizCanvas() {
        quiz_div = document.getElementById("bf-quiz");
    },

    // Parses the JSON data passed from the Loader
    getJSONData = function getJSONData(json_data) {
        //Main Quiz Title
        quiz_title = json_data[0].quiz_title;
        //Main Quiz Image
        quiz_image = json_data[0].quiz_image;
        //Populates questions arrary with questions from JSON file
        for (var i = 0; i < json_data[0].quiz_questions.length; i++) {
            questions.push(json_data[0].quiz_questions[i]);
        }
        //Populates results array with results from JSON file
        for (var j = 0; j < json_data[0].quiz_results.length; j++) {
            results.push(json_data[0].quiz_results[j]);
        }
    },

    // Writes the Quiz into the document
    writeQuiz = function writeQuiz() {
        var newQuizWrapper, newTitle, newQuestionTextWrapper, newQuestionText,
            newAnswerForm, newAnswer, newAnswerImage, newAnswerTextWrapper, newAnswerInput,
            newAnswerText, newQuestion;
        newQuizWrapper = document.createElement("div");
        newQuizWrapper.className = "quiz-wrapper";
        newTitle = document.createElement("h1");
        newTitle.innerHTML = quiz_title;
        newQuizWrapper.appendChild(newTitle);
        for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
            newQuestionTextWrapper = document.createElement("div");
            newQuestionTextWrapper.className = "quiz-question-text-wrapper";
            newQuestionText = document.createElement("h2");
            newQuestionText.innerHTML = questions[i].question.text;
            newQuestionTextWrapper.appendChild(newQuestionText);
            newAnswerForm = document.createElement("form");
            for (var j = 0; j < questions[i].question.question_answers.length; j++) {
                newAnswer = document.createElement("div");
                newAnswer.className = "quiz-answer";
                newAnswer.setAttribute("data-quizValue", 
                    questions[i].question.question_answers[j].answer.value);
                if (questions[i].question.question_answers[j].answer.image) {
                    newAnswerImage = document.createElement("img");
                    newAnswerImage.src = questions[i].question.question_answers[j].answer.image;
                    newAnswer.appendChild(newAnswerImage);
                }
                else{
                    //no image  
                }
                newAnswerTextWrapper = document.createElement("div");
                newAnswerTextWrapper.className = "quiz-answer-text-wrapper";
                newAnswerTextWrapper.id = "quiz-answer-text-wrapper";
                newAnswerInput = document.createElement("input");
                newAnswerInput.type = "radio";
                newAnswerInput.name = "answer";
                inputs.push(newAnswerInput);
                newAnswerText = document.createElement("label");
                newAnswerText.htmlFor = "quizzer";
                newAnswerText.innerHTML = questions[i].question.question_answers[j].answer.text;
                newAnswerTextWrapper.appendChild(newAnswerInput);
                newAnswerTextWrapper.appendChild(newAnswerText);
                newAnswer.appendChild(newAnswerTextWrapper);
                answers.push(newAnswer);
                newAnswerForm.appendChild(newAnswer);
            }
            newQuestion = document.createElement("div");
            newQuestion.className = "quiz-question";
            newQuestion.appendChild(newQuestionTextWrapper);
            newQuestion.appendChild(newAnswerForm);
            newQuizWrapper.appendChild(newQuestion);
        }
        quiz_div.appendChild(newQuizWrapper);
    },

    //Checks all of the inputs to see if the
    checkInputs = function checkInputs() {
        var c = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            if (inputs[i].checked) {
                userAnswers.push(inputs[i].parentNode.parentNode.dataset.quizvalue);
                c++;
            }
        }
        if (c==questions.length) {
                calcResult();
        }
    },

    calcResult = function calcResult() {
        var highest = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            results[i].countof = 0;
            for (var j = 0; j < userAnswers.length; j++) {
                if (userAnswers[j] == results[i].result.id) {
                    results[i].countof++;
                }
            }
            if (results[i].countof > highest) {
                highest = results[i].countof;
                highest_score = results[i];
            }
        }
        //disable the inputs after the quiz is finished
        writeResult();
        disableAnswers();
    },

    writeResult = function writeResult() {
        newResult = document.createElement("div");
        //append html to render (quiz result)
        ...;
        quiz_div.appendChild(newResult);
    },

    updateSelectedAnswer = function updateSelectedAnswer(element) {
        element.children.namedItem("quiz-answer-text-wrapper").firstChild.checked = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < element.parentNode.children.length; i++) {
            if (element.parentNode.children.item(i).hasClass("selected")) {
                element.parentNode.children.item(i).removeClass("selected");
            }
        }
        element.className = element.className + " selected";
    },

    addClickEvents = function addClickEvents() {
        var onAnswerClick = function onAnswerClick() {
                if (!this.hasAttribute("disabled")) {
                    updateSelectedAnswer(this);
                    checkInputs();
            }
        };
        for (var i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
            answers[i].addEventListener("click", onAnswerClick);
        }
    },

    disableAnswers = function disableAnswers() {
        for (var q = 0; q < answers.length; q++) {
            answers[q].disabled = true;
            answers[q].setAttribute("disabled", true);
            answers[q].className = answers[q].className + " disabled";
        }
    };

    return {
        init: function (json_data) {
            getQuizCanvas();
            getJSONData(json_data);
            writeQuiz();
            addClickEvents();
        }
    };
}();

BF_QUIZ.quizLoader = function () {
    "use strict";

    var json_data, request,

    loadQuizJSON = function loadQuizJSON(json_url) {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("GET", json_url, false);
        request.onload = function() {
            if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
                // Success!
                json_data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            } else {
                // We reached our target server, but it returned an error
            }
        };
        request.onerror = function() {
            // There was a connection error of some sort
        };
        request.send();
    };

    return {
        init: function(json_url) {
            loadQuizJSON(json_url);
            BF_QUIZ.quiz.init(json_data);
        }
    };
}();
```

Comment: Why don't you narrow the code down to just the part that isn't working, then do some logging to a div on the page to see what's going on? It is probably a feature being used that isn't supported in the mobile browser. Also, there is a `...;` in `writeResult` that will throw an exception, what is supposed to be there?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to share a working plunker with json? It would be easier to answer question by testing the problem.

Comment: Share a working page link

Comment: @azs06  Here is a link, it works on desktop, but not mobile http://plnkr.co/edit/tkCQVxoIq9oOiApeUY66?p=preview

Comment: @SagarV here is a link http://plnkr.co/edit/tkCQVxoIq9oOiApeUY66?p=preview -- it works on desktop but not mobile (when you click the run view, to see in mobil it needs to be opened as just run.pln...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your plunker, if you update your code on line 152 from `newResultTitle.style = "color:rgba(238,62,52,.99);";` to `newResultTitle.style.color = "rgba(238,62,52,.99)";` this would make it work on mobile browsers.

HTMLElement.style reruns a read only property, desktop browser ignoring it when you are trying to assign a value to it, and mobile browser throwing an error.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style

Working plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/aVxTP5YCbL94v2GI0IKh?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

If you ever try to see console log on a mobile device, you might notice that there is a JavaScript error because iOS Safari is less forgiving than whatever desktop browser you use. Particularly it is illegal to set `style` property of `HTMLElement` as string in `strict` mode. You may see examples of the ways to set it properly at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style If you fix this issue, code seems to be working on Mobile Safari as well.

P.S. note that the offending code is ***missing*** in your question and is only visible in the full code of `writeResult` on plunker. This is why it is so important to provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)